# How to convert int16 to hex-encoded string in Golang

Tags: go

I need to convert the data format of an int16 to a string representing its hexadecimal value.

I have tried some hex converters but they change the data instead of changing the formatting. I need it to be a string representation of its hexadecimal value.

```
data := (data from buffer)

fmt.Printf("BUFFER DATA : %X\n", data) // output print on screen D9DC (hex)
fmt.Println(("BUFFER DATA : ", string(data)) // output print on screen 55772 (dec)
fmt.Println(("BUFFER DATA : ", data) // output print on screen [?]
```

How can I convert the data format so it prints `D9DC` with `fmt.Println`?

Full code here https://play.golang.org/p/WVpMb9lh1Rx

Answer (score 2):

Since [`fmt.Println`](https://godoc.org/fmt#Println) doesn't accept format flags, it prints each variable depending on its type.

[`crc16.Checksum`](https://godoc.org/github.com/howeyc/crc16#Checksum) returns an int16, so `fmt.Println` will display the integer value of your hexadecimal string, which is `55772`.

If you want `fmt.Println` to print `D9DC` instead of the integer value, you have multiple choices.

- Convert your integer into a string that contains the hexadecimal value (which means if you change your integer, you will need to convert it into a string again before using it
- Create your own type with a `String()` method, which is an integer but is represented by its hexadecimal value when printed.

For the second option, your type could be something like this:

```golang
type Hex int16

func (h Hex) String() string {
    return strconv.FormatInt(int64(h), 16)
}
```

`fmt.Println` will automatically use this method because it means the `Hex` type implements the [`Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface. For more info on this, here are some resources:

- https://tour.golang.org/methods/17
- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer